# Building a class and method heirachy from MEF imports

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I'm trying to build an application that uses the Managed Entity Framework to import a unknown number of classes and their related methods.

For example I have the following 2 classes:

```
interface IClass { }

[Export(typeof(IClass))]
class Class1 : IClass
{
    [Export(typeof(Func<int>))]        
    public int GetNumber()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

[Export(typeof(IClass))]
class Class2 : IClass
{
    [Export(typeof(Func<int>))]
    public int GetNumber1()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    [Export(typeof(Func<int>))]
    public int GetNumber2()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

`Class1` has a single `GetNumber` method, whilst `Class2` has two.

In my program I am able to create imports that load the classes and methods.

```
class Program
{   
    [ImportMany]
    IEnumerable<IClass> Classes { get; set; }

    [ImportMany(typeof(Func<int>))]
    IEnumerable<Func<int>> Methods { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.Run();
        Console.Read();
    }

    void Run()
    {
        AssemblyCatalog catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        container.ComposeParts(this);

        if(this.Classes.Count() != 2)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        this.Methods.ToList().ForEach(m => Console.WriteLine(m()));
    }
}
```

**Output**

- 1
- 1
- 2

The problem I have is that link between class and method has been lost. As all classes and methods are thrown into the same `IEnumerable`, I can't tell which class was linked to which method.

I really want to build an in memory structure similar which models the hierarchy of class and method, e.g.

Class1: GetNumber

Class2: GetNumber1, GetNumber2

How can I import these same classes and method but retain the class to method link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable by using `container.GetExportedValues`, this will expose the the classes and methods. They can then be grouped up and composed into the preferred structure. You don't actually need the `[ImportMany]` at all. This feels a little backwards, given MEF is meant to be performing the composition for you, but it works in this case.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.Run();
        Console.Read();
    }

    void Run()
    {
        AssemblyCatalog catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        Dictionary<IClass, List<Func<int>>> dictionary = new Dictionary<IClass, List<Func<int>>>();

        IEnumerable<IClass> classes = container.GetExportedValues<IClass>();
        IEnumerable<Func<int>> methods = container.GetExportedValues<Func<int>>();

        foreach(var c in classes)
        {
            dictionary[c] = new List<Func<int>>();
        }

        foreach(var m in methods)
        {
            dictionary[(IClass)m.Target].Add(m);
        }            

        foreach(var kvp in dictionary)
        {
            kvp.Value.ForEach(m => Console.WriteLine(m()));
        }
    }
}
```

If you need the metadata use `container.GetExports`.